Adding a Translator Ressource is not working
I want to work in the Azure Language Studio, but adding a Translator Ressource is not working.
Error: "Your translator resource must have a "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role in the Azure Blob storage account to run document translation jobs".
Error and Selection :

The problem is that I added and rechecked all the needed "Storage Blob Data Contributor" Roles for the Managed identities, but I still get the error.
Assigned Roles :

I don't know what to try next to make it work.

I understand that you have granted the RBAC role to your Managed Identity.
Action Plan:
Please assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to your Azure portal login User account on the Azure Storage account. Post that, wait atleast 20 minutes for the role to propagate and then test from the language studio.
I hope this helps.
